# Moquery & Grep - Returning results for classes without a specific attribute

Tags: networking, grep, cisco

Good afternoon!

I'm looking to execute a query on a number of classes and return only those classes that lack a specific attribute.

For example, In the program I am using, assume that I have a class `Car` - A car in this example has an object `Tyres` - The object `Tyres` can have 1 or more attributes:

`Brand 1`
`Brand 2`
`Brand 3`

What I looking to do is run a query and return the classes that either:

Do NOT have Brand 1

The problem I am having, is that when I run this query and grep the results, it seems to return all classes and simply omitting Brand 1 instead of returning classes that meet the above requirements.

For example, if class `Car_1` has object `Tyres` with for the purpose of this argument, has 3 attributes for this object, `Brand 1 Brand 2 Brand 3` - I only want to show the classes that do NOT have Brand 3 - Instead, Grep seems to return this class with Brand 3 omitted instead.

What is the best solution to achieve what I am after?

I apologise in advanced for the evident vagueness, I'm trying to be neutral with the program I am using as to focus only on Grepping the results in the correct way.

Cheers!

Comment: This is far too vague to even begin to answer.  What kind of data does mockery return? plain text? json? xml?  Something else? What exact command are you running, with what options? What output do you get?  (feel free to redact any sensitive information like names or addresses, but show the actual structure with bogus data if necessary).

Comment: According to [cisco's moquery cheat sheet](https://community.cisco.com/t5/data-center-and-cloud-documents/aci-object-moquery-cheat-sheet/ta-p/3367801) and a blog post at https://rednectar.net/2020/04/09/moquery-ciscos-mysterious-obscure-aci-query-utility/, it outputs records with `key:value` pairs, each record starting with `#`.   `grep` is the wrong tool for this, but if you piped that into `sed 's/^#/\n/'`, you could process it "paragraph mode" with perl.  perl can apply regexes to multi-line strings, so you could skip entire records that contain "Brand1", not just a single matching line.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
moquery ..... |
  sed -e 's/^#/\n#/' |
  perl -00 -ne 'print unless /^Tyres\h*:.*\bBrand 1\b/mig'
```

The `sed` script inserts a newline character before each `#`.  This makes it suitable for processing in "paragraph mode" in `perl` (or `awk`).  A "paragraph" is one or more lines of text with at least one empty line between them.

In short, `sed` converts this (sample data taken from the rednectar.net blog post [moquery – Cisco’s Mysterious Obscure ACI query utility](https://rednectar.net/2020/04/09/moquery-ciscos-mysterious-obscure-aci-query-utility/)):

```
# fv.Tenant
name         : Tenant5
dn           : uni/tn-Tenant5
uid          : 15374
# fv.Tenant
name         : common
dn           : uni/tn-common
uid          : 0
# fv.Tenant
name         : Tenant3
dn           : uni/tn-Tenant3
uid          : 15374
```

to this:

```
# fv.Tenant
name         : Tenant5
dn           : uni/tn-Tenant5
uid          : 15374

# fv.Tenant
name         : common
dn           : uni/tn-common
uid          : 0

# fv.Tenant
name         : Tenant3
dn           : uni/tn-Tenant3
uid          : 15374
```

The Perl script will then print all records except those containing a Tyres entry containing "Brand 1".  The regex is case-insensitive, and uses `\b` word-boundary markers around "Brand 1" so that it doesn't do partial matches (like "Off-Brand 1" or "Brand 100").

If you needed to do more processing on the records (e.g. match other fields, or extract some of the data and do something with it), you could do something like:

```
moquery ..... |
  sed -e 's/^#/\n#/' |
  perl -00 -ne '
    next if /^Tyres\h*:.*\bBrand 1\b/mig;

    ...more perl statements here...;

    print'
```

Or you could write a stand-alone perl script rather than a one-liner using `-n`.

---

See also: [ACI object moquery Cheat Sheet](https://community.cisco.com/t5/data-center-and-cloud-documents/aci-object-moquery-cheat-sheet/ta-p/3367801)  from Cisco's community web site.